# Jmeter - Different ip addres for each thread when testing using load generators in the cloud

Tags: jmeter

My current set up is JMeter script 200 users per load generator (in the cloud using AWS) i have 10 generators (2000 threads).

In the set up we have a load balancer which does a round robin, however the load generators sometimes balances and other times it uses one or two app servers more then the others (total of 10). In a real life environment we would have each thread with a different ip address therefore they would balance correctly.

Is there a away of each thread having its own IP address. (currently each load generator has its own IP address)

I need this to work on my current setup. Any ideas welcome.

JMeter version 2.13 or 3.1

Comment: useful info https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 10 different load generators with 10 different IPs, and 10 application servers behind the load balancer, I would expect the load balancer to assign a single application per load generator if your assumption is correct.

You may have:

- load balancer misconfiguration, which causes all the clients to be rooted to a single application server (sticky sessions?),
- or load testing script misconfiguration (dynamic parameters not handled correctly ?) causing all the users to use the same login / session which would cause the load balancer to send them to the same application server.

I would start by monitoring the application servers and load balancers with a single load generator to see if the users are all sent to the same application server. Then try with 2 load generators (with different IPs), to see if 2 application servers are being hit.

Some paid tools support [infrastructure monitoring](https://octoperf.com/blog/2016/10/13/monitoring-introduction/). You could use a free account and simulate a test in multiple regions (to have multiple IPs) to find out.

Other resources:

- [Apache Httpd Monitoring](https://doc.octoperf.com/monitoring/apache-httpd/)
- [Apache Tomcat Monitoring](https://doc.octoperf.com/monitoring/apache-tomcat/)

There are also free monitoring tools like [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) which can be used in parallel of your custom JMeter AWS Setup.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are setting different source addresses for HTTP requests, check out http://blog.milamberspace.net/index.php/2009/12/03/changer-ladresse-ip-source-dune-requete-http-lors-dun-test-avec-jmeter-549.html article for more information.

Also it may be due to OS or JVM caching of your DNS requests, especially if your application is located behind the [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)

Make you sure you add [DNS Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan so each JMeter thread would resolve underlying IP addresses on its own. See [The DNS Cache Manager: The Right Way To Test Load Balanced Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) article for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the issue, you need to ensure that the total number of load generators that you are using are in multiples of your number of web servers. Let us say your application has 3 webservers. You can use 3 / 6/ 9 / 12 load generators with load split evenly between all of them. You can't use 4 / 7 / 10 etc. If you do that, you will always see requests going to some web servers more than the others if you are using sticky sessions.